# Extract gain of audio using java

Tags: java, audio, sampling, javasound

I am trying to know the gain / decibels and other possible parameters from wav audio file. But Clip.getLevel() method is always returning gain in -0.1 value.

```
public void prepareAudio() {
    try {
        Line.Info linfo = new Line.Info(Clip.class);
        Line line = AudioSystem.getLine(linfo);
        clip = (Clip) line;
        clip.addLineListener(this);
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        clip.open(ais);
        clip.start();
        do {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } while (clip.isActive());
        clip.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void update(LineEvent event) {
    LineEvent.Type type = event.getType();
    if (type == LineEvent.Type.OPEN) {
        System.out.println("OPEN");
    } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.CLOSE) {
        System.out.println("CLOSE");
    } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.START) {
        System.out.println("START");
        while (clip.isActive()) {
            System.out.println(clip.getLevel()); // get gain
        }
    } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
        System.out.println("STOP");
        clip.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have to abandon the Clip. OK?

Answer (score 0):

The method [getLevel()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#getLevel()) gives you the (linear) gain of the `DataLine`, which is used for playback, *not* some property of the audio file. As of now, there is no built-in method in JavaSE to determine such a thing. In order to measure what's in the file, consider studying [ReplayGain](https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=ReplayGain_2.0_specification) or [EBU R128](https://tech.ebu.ch/docs/r/r128.pdf). A free and open implementation of EBU R128 is [libebur128](https://github.com/jiixyj/libebur128), but it's not in Java.